# How to add an option for js code in grapesjs?

Tags: javascript, extract, grapesjs

[image]

Now I want my JS code also to be exported? How is this done?
I have seen that in the block manager if we edit the content as follows

```
editor.BlockManager.add("sample input field", {
  label: "input-field",
  category: "sample",
  content: {
            script:"my script"
           }
});
```

the script is embedded in my HTML file but if I edit it as follows

```
content:` some HTML code
<script type="text/javascript" myscript></script>`
```

I do not get the script content in my HTML file....how to get the script embedded in the content?
Why is it not being displayed in the extracted HTML file?

Comment: How did you solve it?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the allowScripts config option when initializing your grapesjs editor.

```
const editor = grapesjs.init({
    ... // the rest of your grapesjs config
    allowScripts: 1,
});
```

Scripts are disabled by default, but this option turns them on.

Comment: can we add script with styles?

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom code. You can check the default view code, in that buildEditor function is there where all config is done.  Along with HTML, CSS, pass Js also

```
const oHtmlEd = buildEditor('htmlmixed', 'hopscotch', 'HTML', editor);
const oCsslEd = buildEditor('css', 'hopscotch', 'CSS', editor);
const oJSlEd = buildEditor('js', 'hopscotch', 'JS', editor);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const editor = grapesjs.init({
  canvas: {
        scripts: ['https://.../somelib.min.js'],
        // The same would be for external styles
        styles: ['https://.../ext-style.min.css'],
       }
   });
```

[Source](https://grapesjs.com/docs/modules/Components-js.html#template-related)